# Javascript OOP - how to inherit methods from the base class to the child without override them?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

How to inherit a base `class` in JavaScript and inherit its `methods` too without need to override them into the new child class again and to call the base implementation of the `method` inside the body of the overridden method.

I cant find any answer of this question. Only ways to inherit and after that if I want to the use the methods of the base class with the instance of the child class I have to override them into the child class.

EDIT: Let me be more specific of my problem. Here is the code i have -->

Base class:

```
var app = app || {};

(function(app){

    function Element(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, someClass, type, href){
        if (this.constructor === Element) {
            throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract class!");
        }

        this._backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this._text = text;
        this._id = id;
        this._tag = tag;
        this._someClass = someClass;
        this._type = type;
        this._href = href;
    }
    Element.prototype.getTag = function(){
        return this._tag;
    };

    Element.prototype.setTag = function(tag){
        this._tag = tag;
    };

    Element.prototype.getClass = function(){
        return this._someClass;
    };

    Element.prototype.setClass = function(someClass){
        this._someClass = someClass;
    };

    Element.prototype.getType = function(){
        return this._type;
    };

    Element.prototype.setType = function(type){
        this._type = type;
    };

    Element.prototype.getHref = function(){
        return this._href;
    };

    Element.prototype.setHref = function(href){
        this._href = href;
    };

    Element.prototype.getId = function(){
        return this._id;
    };

    Element.prototype.setId = function(id){
        this._id = id;
    };

    Element.prototype.getBackgroundColor = function(){
        return this._backgroundColor;
    };

    Element.prototype.setBackgroundColor = function(backgroundColor){
        this._backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    };

    Element.prototype.getText = function(){
        return this._text;
    };

    Element.prototype.setText = function(text){
        this._text = text;
    };


    Element.prototype.render = function(){
        var stringElement = '<' + this.getTag() + 'style="background-color:' + this.getBackgroundColor() + '" id=' + this.getId() + 'class=' + this.getClass() + ' ';

        if(this.getType()){
            stringElement += 'type=' + this.getType() + '>' + this.getText() + '</' + this.getTag() + '>';
        }
        else if(this.getHref()){
            stringElement += '><a href="' + this.getHref() + '">' + this.getText() + '</a>' + '</' + this.getTag() + '>';
        }
        else{
            stringElement += '>' + this.getText() + '</' + this.getTag() + '>';
        }

        $('#container').append(stringElement);
    };

    app.Element1 = Element;

    app.prototype= function(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, type, href){
        return new Element(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, type, href);
    }


})(app);
```

Child class:

```
var app = app || {};

app.linkButton = (function(app){

    function LinkButton(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, someClass, type, href){
        app.Element1.call(this, backgroundColor, text, id, tag, someClass, type, href);
    }
    console.log(Element);
    LinkButton.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
    LinkButton.prototype.constructor = LinkButton;

    return {
        load: function(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, someClass, type, href){
            return new LinkButton(backgroundColor, text, id, tag, someClass, type, href);
        }
    }
})(app);
```

The class where i'm trying to use the element(base class) methods with a linkButton(child class) instance -->

```
var app = app || {};

app.toolBar = (function(){

    var counterText = 0;

    function ToolBar() {}

    ToolBar.prototype.render = function(){
        $("#menu").append("<button id='button1' class='mainButtons' name='realButtons'>Add Text</button><button id='button2' class='mainButtons'>Add Link</button>");
        $('.mainButtons').draggable({cancel:false});
    };

    ToolBar.prototype.init = function(){
        this.render();
        var _this = this;
        var counter = 0;
        $('#button1').click(function(){
            var elementText = app.textButton.load();
            _this.createElement(elementText);
            counter++;
        });
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            var textId = 'l_' + counter;
            var href = 'someLink.com';
            var elementLink = app.linkButton.load('#001a13', 'someText', textId,'div','textButton', null, href );

            _this.createElement(elementLink);
            counter++;
        });
    };


    ToolBar.prototype.createElement = function(element){
        console.log(element);
        element.render();
        var el = '#'+ element.getId();
        $(el).draggable();
            $(el).ColorPicker({
                color: element.getBackgroundColor(),
                eventName: "dblclick",
                onShow: function(colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(300);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function(colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $(el).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                    element.setBackgroundColor(hex);
                }
            });
    };

   return {
       load: function(){
           return new ToolBar();
       }
   }
}());
```

The problem is that when i try to use .render() function into the create element function i got this error :  ***"element.render() is not a function"***

All the classes are in different files. I call them into my index file like that :

```
<script src="js/element.js"></script>
<script src="js/linkButton.js"></script>
<script src="js/textButton.js"></script>
<script src="js/toolBar.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: This might be helpful - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: How are you currently trying to "inherit" the base class? Using the correct prototype-based extension method will do just fine without re-declaring the methods. Have you tried that? Have you tried following official documents/tutorials for how to use inheritance in Javascript?

Comment: you can use method of base class(object) without overriding.

Comment: I edited the post to be more specific.

Comment: I really need help here because i cant understand where i get wrong.